# File CSV with pipe (|) but I've pipe in the middle of the field

Tags: python, pandas, pipe

I have a CSV file, generate by ERP, the delimiter is pipe (|). But in this file I have columns with the format in ERP is Text and the users in many lines put pipe(|) in the middle of the text
ex
|100019391 |99806354    |**EV | RES: Consulta COBRO VVISTA - Chile**           |31|24.06.2021|

this part EV | Res***  is the field where de user put pipe.

My error is, when the pand read this lines, it give me a Error

*Skipping line 46: Expected 28 fields in line 46, saw 29*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6stn.png)

Is there a option to fix it?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no space exists after the pipe separator, then we can use the following regex `r"\|(?!\s)"` for the `sep` argument.

Sample input:

```
col|col1|col2|col3|col4|
100019391 |99806354 |EV | RES: Consulta COBRO VVISTA - Chile |31|24.06.2021|
100019392 |99806777 |TEST - Chile |31|25.06.2021|
100019393 |99806779 |TE | ST - Chile |31|25.06.2021|
```

Then, we can import the above csv as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename,
  usecols=range(5),
  sep=r"\|(?!\s)",
  lineterminator='\r',
  engine='python')
```

Adjust `usecols` according to the number of columns you have. Adjust `lineterminator` according to the line terminator being used in your file. The `engine='python'` is required as python will throw a warning for using regex in `sep`.

Pic of the output

[image: Picture of the output]

Comment: Hi garagnothT.  ks for the answer

Unfortunately I have lines in the CSV file where  doesn't have nothing inside the pipe

|Customer   |Reference      |Due date  |
|374696       |                      |16.01.2019|
|390531       |002                |11.02.2017|

Ex. in the first line the field reference is empty

thanks